# Confusion how HOC are used in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across something called higher order component and also found this code:

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        data: selectData(DataSource, props)
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      // ... that takes care of the subscription...
      DataSource.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      DataSource.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    }

    handleChange() {
      this.setState({
        data: selectData(DataSource, this.props)
      });
    }

    render() {
      // ... and renders the wrapped component with the fresh data!
      // Notice that we pass through any additional props
      return <WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

Well, basically it is clear what HOC does it accepts a component and returns enhanced version of that accepted component. But what confuses me is that how the component can be returned since we do not call render method, that is, we just need to do this withSubscription(someComponent) and enhanced someComponent will be returned but we do not call render method which actually returns that enhanced component.How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean how is it possible? The render method returns an *element*, like any other component's, then the React runtime is responsible for rendering the element.

Comment: As the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) say: "HOCs are not part of the React API". They're just a pattern that allows you to reuse component logic. If you're just learning React, it might not immediately obvious how they can help. When you start seeing duplicate component logic, you might find that implementing one helps abstract a specific functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually confusing HOC with a `React Component`.

The name is misleading.

HOC is not a concept unqiue to `React`. This is a concept that is derived from the world of `functional programming.`

In functional programming we have **Higher Order Functions (HOF)**

 A HOF is a function that takes another function as a parameter.

Consider the following example:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

`greaterThan` is higher order function, it accepts a function as a parameter.
`.map`,`.filter` in JS are too HOF. They take function as a parameter.

Similarily we have HOCs.

#### Formal definition of HOC

> A higher-order component is a function that takes a component and
>   returns a new component.

Did you notice it?
It is not a `component`. It is a ***function*** that takes a `component` as a parameter. It also returns a `component`.

**Consider the following example:**

```
const hocWrapper = (PassedComponent) =>
  ({ children, ...props }) =>
    <PassedComponent {...props}>
      {children.split("").reverse().join("")}
    </PassedComponent>

const name = (props) => <span>{props.children}</span>
const reversedName = hocWrapper(name)
<reversedName>Hello</reversedName>
```

In the above example we have

1. HOC - hocWrapper
2. PassedComponent - React Component
3. Return value - React Component [with enhanced functionality]

hocWrapper is a ***simple function*** which takes ***PassedComponent*** as a parameter and returns an ***enhanced version of PassedComponent***.

Comment: exactly like you did, the react documentation should state explicitly that a higher order component is not a react component.